# How to get information out of the database with $_SESSION?

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, so I have a database with a table 'users'. I also have a registration and login system on my website. Everytime when someone registers all their information is put into the table 'users' in my database. When someone logs in they have to use their e-mail and password and both of those are in a row in my database. I can use the e-mail of the logged in person thanks to $_SESSION["Email"]; and do things with their email like a welcome message(Welcome, $_SESSION["Email"];. I now have a question for you guys. I want to make a profile page where the users can edit their information. Is there any way for me to get all of the information in my database from the logged in person? I'm guessing I have to use $_SESSION["Email"], and then write a query that gives me all of the information of the logged in person?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: Yep, you're correct.

Comment: It's probably a good idea not to store too much user data in the session.

Comment: And how exactly do I get all of the information from the person who's logged in? I can get the Email of the person who's logged in, but how do I get the rest then?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your SESSION filled with all the editable fields, you can extract the information from the SESSION to the form, and after that send the FORM to another page that will check/validate the form and then perform an UPDATE query in the database.

Here's an example:

```
$sql = "select * from users where email='".$_REQUEST['email']."' and password='".$_REQUEST['password']."'";
$data = getInformationFromDatabase();
if(!empty($data)){
    $_SESSION['logged'] = $data;
    $email = $_SESSION['logged']['email'];
}

//-- To update you would have the data into your SESSION to fill the initial values of the form
//-- The user would change those values and send to the server by GET or POST
//-- Change the values in the session like:
$_SESSION['logged']['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
//-- Change the values in the database like:
$sql = "update users set email='".$_REQUEST['email']."' WHERE email='".$oldEmail."';
//-- Execute the query
```

Comment: Yes, but I can only put that information in SESSIONS after someone has registered. I need to put it in SESSIONS after someone has logged in. At this moment I can only put the Email in a SESSIONS because the person who logged in used his Email to log in.

Comment: How exactly is your login process?

Comment: You have to check the login information in your database and if it's correct you must register the values of user to the SESSION. If that's not how you're doing it something is very wrong.